# How to setup dart.yml to run tests with build_runner

Tags: github, dart, continuous-integration, github-actions, dart-pub

I am trying to set up Continuous Integration (CI) for my Dart project, but I am getting a file not found error when I run `pub run build_runner test`:

```
Failed to run Chrome: No such file or directory
```

You can see the full job executed [here](https://github.com/UC-Davis-molecular-computing/scadnano/runs/434176213).

I have tried setting up the `dart.yml` sticking to the [default](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/master/ci/dart.yml), but I altered the last line from `pub run test` to `pub run build_runner test` as required by the [OverReact Framework](https://github.com/Workiva/over_react#running-tests-in-your-project).

So my `dart.yml` reads:

```yaml
name: Dart CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    container:
      image:  google/dart:latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: pub get
    - name: Run tests
      run: pub run build_runner test
```

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Well, your problem is that google-chrome is not installed in the container you are using. You either need to find a container with contain the google-chrome executable or make a step before you tests which installs google-chrome.

Comment: @julemand101 But according to the Github Actions [documentation](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/software-installed-on-github-hosted-runners) chrome should already be installed.

Answer (score 2):

It is correct that `ubuntu-latest` contains `google-chrome` but since you have the following in your configuration:

```yaml
container:
  image:  google/dart:latest
```

It means your ubuntu image are spawning a docker container based on `google/dart:latest` and runs the rest of your script inside this container. I have extracted the content of `/usr/bin` on both `google/dart:latest` and `ubuntu-latest` which can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/julemand101/1e74aee8e5152fb18b4913bbeaf805b6)

As we can see from this output, the `google/dart:latest` container does not have the `google-chrome` executable — I have looked around in other places in the image and could not spot it. But `ubuntu-latest` does contain it.

Since Dart SDK is a lot easier to install than google chrome, I guess the easiest way to solve the problem is to install the Dart SDK in the `ubuntu-latest` image — and therefore not use the container feature in Github action — as multiple install steps which follows [this guide](https://dart.dev/get-dart#install-using-apt-get).

And, after this, then run the rest of your script as normal. I have tried make an example of this here:

```yaml
name: Dart CI

on:
  - push

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Setup Dart SDK Step 1
      run: sudo apt-get update
    - name: Setup Dart SDK Step 2
      run: sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
    - name: Setup Dart SDK Step 3
      run: sudo sh -c 'wget -qO- https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -'
    - name: Setup Dart SDK Step 4
      run: sudo sh -c 'wget -qO- https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian/dart_stable.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dart_stable.list'
    - name: Setup Dart SDK Step 5
      run: sudo apt-get update
    - name: Setup Dart SDK Step 6
      run: sudo apt-get -y install dart

    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/dart/bin" pub get
    - name: Run tests
      run: PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/dart/bin" pub run test
    - name: Run analyzer
      run: PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/dart/bin" dartanalyzer --fatal-infos --fatal-warnings .
      if: always()
    - name: Run dartfmt
      run: PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/dart/bin" dartfmt -n --set-exit-if-changed .
      if: always()
```

You can also check out the code [here](https://github.com/julemand101/AdventOfCode2019/blob/85475933c1cc5617610c9287b03813fde748039a/.github/workflows/dart.yml). And you can see a successful build [here](https://github.com/julemand101/AdventOfCode2019/runs/438192908).

Comment: Dang it. Spot on. Great answer.